# Change where mouse pointer activates?

Tags: cursor, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to get a custom mouse cursor setup. I know how to change the image file (.ani or .cur), that's simple enough. The issue that I run into is where the actually point registers its own location. It's not that same as the default pointer.

So specifically, when the default pointer is hovering over a menu option or something the box highlights. The pointer is pointing at that spot, it's not just activating with the cursor image. If you imagined the cursor in a box, the pointer would be in the top left corner, right? That's normal.
So, with my custom cursor, the activation point moves to the bottom left corner and it's a little annoying. Anyway to change this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Any cursor editor, whether installed (https://listoffreeware.com/free-cursor-maker-software-windows/) or online (e.g., http://www.rw-designer.com/online-cursor-editor) lets you set the hotspot at any point in the image.